# How to make next button in a multistep form inactive until the input element has a value or is checked or filled?

Tags: javascript, html

I created a simple multistep form where...

First Step: has 1 heading "Do you like fruits?" + Has 2 radio input with label "Yes" and "No"+ 1 Next btn

Second Step: has 1 heading "Which fruit do you like?". Has 2 radio input with label "Apple" and "Grape" + 1 Prev btn & 1 Next btn

Third Step: has 1 heading "Why don't you like fruit?". Has 1 input field with placeholder "Enter Reason" + 1 Prev btn & 1 Next btn

And I am trying to make the next button disabled by default and should go active only after input field has a value or is checked.

The below JS code is created by GPT and it is doing the reverse – When fields are empty then next button is active, when field are filled or checked... next button is disabled.

```js
const inputFields = document.querySelectorAll('input'); // Replace 'input' with the selector for your input fields
inputFields.forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener('change', validateInput);
});


function validateInput(event) {
  const currentStep = event.target.closest('.form-section'); // Replace '.step' with the selector for your step element
  const inputsInStep = currentStep.querySelectorAll('input'); // Replace 'input' with the selector for your input fields
  const nextButton = currentStep.querySelector('.form-next-btn'); // Replace '.next-button' with the selector for your Next button

  // Check if all required input fields in the current step have values or are checked
  const allInputsValid = [...inputsInStep].every(input => {
    if (input.type === 'checkbox' || input.type === 'radio') {
      return input.checked;
    }
    return input.value.trim() !== '';
  });

  // Enable or disable the Next button based on the input validation
  nextButton.disabled = !allInputsValid;
}



const nextButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.form-next-btn'); // Replace '.next-button' with the selector for your Next buttons
nextButtons.forEach((button, index) => {
  if (index === 0) {
    button.disabled = false;
  } else {
    button.disabled = true;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just change your last part to this. This will disable all next buttons initially. The current next button will only enable based on the condition in your `validateInput` function

```
const nextButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.form-next-btn');
nextButtons.forEach(button => {
    button.disabled = true;
});
```